# Sencha Touch 2 assigning variables

Tags: variables, sencha-touch-2

I have a Store which collects data via proxy. I use the data to create an ItemList, successfully.

**My problem is I'm trying assign the data from the store to variables for later use.**

The only place I can use the data is :

```
itemTpl: '{term} - {tid}',
```

The first variable (term) is a string and tid is an integer. I need to use the integer separately but it seems I can't use the data except in the format above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a Sencha Touch store for example in the `YourApp/store` directory you can use the store (and it's data) globally.

An example:

Your model & store could be something like...

```
Ext.define('YourApp.model.Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
           {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'term', type: 'string'}
        ]
    }
});


Ext.define('YourApp.store.Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        storeId:'exampleStore',
        model: 'YourApp.model.Example',
        proxy: {} //your proxy config
    }
});
```

If you have a populated store (as you seem to have) you could use it to populate select fields, lists, ...whatever using its storeId.

```
{
   xtype: 'selectfield',
   label: 'Term',
   name: 'term',
   store: 'exampleStore', //storeId
   displayField: 'term',
   valueField: 'id'
}
```

Or you can access the store and it's data manually using the stores `getData()` or `getRange()` method. (see http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

```
var store = Ext.getStore('exampleStore'); //storeId
console.log(store.getData().all[index_of_record]); //record
console.log(store.getData().all[index_of_record].data); //data object

console.log(store.getData().all[index_of_record].data.id); //id property
console.log(store.getData().all[index_of_record].data.term); //term property
```

Comment: Dude! Thank you so very much. One week of pain almost over. Thanks